# How to convert ascii integer to char in C#?

Tags: c#, int, ascii

OK so I don't get yelled at I did search the forums and there is a very similar question, I'm just having a little difficulty understanding what is meant.

I'm generating a random number in decimal, checking to see if it matches a certain exclusion range for characters I don't want to print, if it does not match the exclusion range, I save the int and I want to send it to the char to be printed.

I don't know how to tell visual studio to print the decimal integer 65 as the char "A" heres my code:

```
int asciVal = rnd.Next(33, 96);
if (asciVal == 48 || asciVal == 49 || asciVal == 50 || asciVal == 51 || asciVal == 52 || asciVal == 53 || asciVal == 54 || asciVal == 55 || asciVal == 56 || asciVal == 57 || asciVal == 65 || asciVal == 66 || asciVal == 67 || asciVal == 68 || asciVal == 69 || asciVal == 70 || asciVal == 71 || asciVal == 72 || asciVal == 73 || asciVal == 74 || asciVal == 75 || asciVal == 76 || asciVal == 77 || asciVal == 78 || asciVal == 79 || asciVal == 80 || asciVal == 81 || asciVal == 82 || asciVal == 83 || asciVal == 84 || asciVal == 85 || asciVal == 86 || asciVal == 87 || asciVal == 88 || asciVal == 89 || asciVal == 90)
    loop = 1;
else {
    loop = 0;
    Text = asciVal;
}
```

Comment: do you have a link to the other question?

Comment: You can shorten your `if` statement:  `if ((asciVal >= 48 && asciVal <= 57) || (asciVal >= 65 && asciVal <= 90))`.  Much more readable than a long line of or statements.

Comment: Several answers and comments show how to convert an integer to a `char` (Unicode/UTF-16 code unit). They are correct because you aren't actually using ASCII. Take what you know about ASCII and port it to [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html), learn a [bit more](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Unicode.aspx) and then forget ASCII.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Convert.ToChar`

```
int number = 65;
char c = Convert.ToChar(number);
```

Comment: and here's the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/3hkfdkcx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to convert an ascii int to char is the following:

```
int i = 123;
char c = (char)i;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the unicode in c#.

```
int asciival= <value>;
char letter = (char) asciival;
string word = letter.ToString();
```